# Why base_pose_ground_truth isn't publishing the real position in stageros?

Tags: ros, stageros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using the stage simulator to make an multi robot experiment. I need a global and perfect position to make it, so the topic base_pose_ground_truth would be perfect for it.

But the problem is that base_pose_ground_truth is not showing the position of the robot as appears in the screen of stage simulator. It's strange because the odometry seems ok, and [description page of Stage stack](http://www.ros.org/wiki/stage) says that base_pose_ground_truth will always publish perfect position.

In most of cases, the x published position is the real y position, and the y published position is the negative of real x position.

I've tested with some .world files of stage stack and navigation_stage package and I got the same problem.

There is an image of an simulation with stageros and the information published in /base_pose_ground_truth (left) and /odom (right). The initial position of the robot was [0 0 0 0].

[image description http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24232831/stage.jpg](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24232831/stage.jpg)

What should I do to make base_pose_ground_truth show the real position?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28561/why-base_pose_ground_truth-isn%27t-publishing-the-real-position-in-stageros?/) by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 497 on 2012-02-26

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2012-08-17**:
same problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,

I modified the stageros code in order to fix this problem. The code can be accesed [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24232831/stageros.cpp). Not all problems were solved, I think that /base_link still wrong. But at least /base_pose_ground_truth topic is working fine. The stageros code is very clear and pretty easy to modify.

Another way to solve this problem is using an localization system, like [amcl](http://www.ros.org/wiki/amcl). But note that amcl has a significant computational cost and it publishes geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped messages, not nav_msgs/Odometry.

---

Originally posted by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) with karma: 497 on 2012-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-18**:
If you made a useful patch to the code, please open a ticket containing a patch file in the stage's bug tracker so that other people also profit from your contribution.